# How to select only one building that have been generated from Blosm for Blender

Tags: blender-osm

I have generated a building, from an Open Street map using Blosm for Blender.

Additionally, I have also used the `Buildify 1.0` to generate the building textures and architecture.

And as an output, I have got the following buildings.

[image]

This is a data in the blender scene collection,

[image]

However, I want to select only one building to export to FBX. And I am not able to select just one building, because I have no experience with the blender tools and command.

Can anyone guide me into the steps on how can I select only one desired building from this list of buildings?

Comment: I would recommend going into edit mode with [TAB], then selecting any part of the single one building you want. Then press [CMD+L] or [Windows+L] to select linked, and it should automatically select the entire mesh. Then if you press P, you can separate the selected part of the mesh from everything else. You should be able to export that single object by itself from there.

Comment: @NascentSpace [Windows+L] locks your desktop, you mean [Ctrl+L] ;) Anyway, if there are separate parts that are not selected at all, [Ctrl+L] will not get them. I would recommend switching to _Wireframe_ mode or enabling _X-Ray_ to make sure hidden parts are selected, too.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ah, my mistake. Thank you for that important clarification.